# Excluding matcher

Tags: javascript, regex

I've tinkered enough with this that i know i won't get anywhere soon.

So i have an object:

```
{
"type": "event name(ID:1992)"
}
```

What i want to do is to select the value that follows the *ID:* . I know it would be easier just to match the numbers, but i want to be extra safe about it and use *ID:* as a starting point for matching. What i have done is the following:

```
/(ID:).*([0-9])+/g
```

The issue is that i have no idea how to exclude the *ID:* from the match. I've played with is a lot on regex101 and didn't manage to find a way.

The result from matching should be *1992" and exclude any other numbers that are not preceded by *ID:*.

Thank you

Comment: `/(ID:)([0-9])+/g`and take the second position of your matching array result would not solve the issue ? Or i maybe misunderstood the issue...

Comment: `()` are for defining capture groups. If you don't want to capture it, remove `()` surrounding **ID:**.

Comment: We only need to capture what we want to keep (usually), and we just match  what we do not need.